# Make component draggable using react-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I'm trying to drag a component using [react-dnd](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/overview)

I would try to make like [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/gh-pages/examples_hooks_js/01-dustbin/single-target?from-embed=&file=/src/Dustbin.jsx:401-407) but only dragging for the moment.

In my app on top of all component I import `react-dnd-html5-backend` and wrap my app:

```
import Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend'
import { DndProvider } from 'react-dnd'

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <FluentuiProvider theme={themes.teams}>
      <DndProvider backend={Backend}>
        <App theme={themes.teams} />
      </DndProvider>
    </FluentuiProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Then in my component:

```
import { useDrag } from 'react-dnd';

export default ({ call, pauseCall, onHoldCalls, endCall, addNote }) => {
  const [collectedProps, drag] = useDrag({
     item: { type: 'Personna' },
  })
  return (
     <div className="personna">
        <Persona ref={drag} {...call.CALL_DETAILS.personInfos["formattedPersData"]} size={PersonaSize.size40} />
     </div>
  )
}
```

When I render the component I get this error

> TypeError: node.setAttribute is not a function
>       at HTML5Backend.connectDragSource (HTML5Backend.js:487)
>       at SourceConnector.reconnectDragSource (SourceConnector.js:115)

I haven't added a `dragSource` because in example it's not used.

I don't know why I'm getting this error message.

Comment: The ref should be given to a HTML element. You are passing it to a `Persona` component. Try to assign the ref to a html DOM like `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Panther said, the `ref` should be placed on a HTML element, not a React Component:

```
return <div ref={drag}>{"Drag me!"}</div>;
```

Or, in your case, you could add the `ref` to the `<div className="personna">` container:

```
return (
     <div ref={drag} className="personna">
        <Persona ....
```

---

To help you get to the minimal drag example, take a look at this very minimal setup:

**App**.js

```
import React from "react";
import Backend from "react-dnd-html5-backend";
import { DndProvider } from "react-dnd";
import { MyComponent } from "./MyComponent";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <DndProvider backend={Backend}>
      <div className="App">
        <MyComponent />
      </div>
    </DndProvider>
  );
}
```

**MyComponent**.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <DndProvider backend={Backend}>
      <div className="App">
        <MyComponent />
      </div>
    </DndProvider>
  );
}
```

[Try it on codesandbox.io!](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-hill-m1niy?file=/App.js)